# Is the asserts statement no longer useful with dart 2?

Tags: dart

I'm reading the dart language tour and see this statement under [**Assert**](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#assert):

> Note: Assert statements work only in checked mode. They have no effect in production mode.

Followed by this statement:

> Dart 2 note: Checked mode won’t be in Dart 2. For more information, see Dart 2 Updates.

Combining the two: since asserts only work in checked mode, and there is no checked mode in Dart 2, are asserts completely invalid once Dart 2 lands?

There are asserts all over the language tutorial, so does something else replace them?

Or, can you run in non-strong mode yet still somehow get the benefits of asserts?

Comment: I also had a similar doubt/question while reading that article. You may open an issue at [`https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues`](https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues), so that the authors of the article can clarify it.

Comment: BTW, the documentation has been updated to remove the parts about "checked mode".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They work in development mode (ddc for web apps, JIT mode for flutter). Yes, `--checked` mode is gone.  But when you use `dart2js` for the web, or `flutter build` for flutter, asserts are all removed.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question "are asserts completely invalid once Dart 2 lands?". If I remember correctly, Dart 2 will be "strong mode" by default, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's my point. I get you can run without strong mode in dart2. But, without strong mode on (what I'm assuming was the equivalent of checked mode), then aren't asserts ignored? And, thereby, ignored in every situation?

Comment: I mean what I said.  I'm sorry it's not clear.  "Always in strong mode" still has two modes: development mode (where asserts work) and deploy mode (where asserts are compiled out).